# C++ While loop and search algorithm, duplicates

Tags: c++, vector, containers

```
for (int j = 0; j < messageVector.size(); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bookVector.size(); i++)
    {
        size_t offset = 0;
        while ((offset = bookVector[i].find(messageVector[j], offset)) != string::npos)
        {
                cout << "Found " << messageVector[j] << " at " << i << "," << offset << std::endl;
                ++offset;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem i'm having with this code is that if the bookvector contains a duplicate letter the letter will be printed both times with both positions. so if the messageVector contained the message "test" but the bookvector contained the alphabet with an extra t, the output would be: found t at i,offset two times and then the rest of the message. This isn't necessarily a problem but I would like for duplicate letters to be only printed once with a random set of coordinates where a t was found being chosen.

I was thinking of a way to solve the problem, I basically have it done in pseudocode, I was going to get all the rows and offset that have the same character, put them in a container, pick a random one. print the found positions to the console with the character, clear the container and move on to the next letter and do it all over again. However I don't know where to do this in the while loop. If someone could help walk me through it it would be nice.

Comment: Is it acceptable solution when you replace type from `std::vector` to `std::set` for `bookVector`varialble? Set will automatically remove duplicates for you.

Comment: yes I just haven't used sets much so I haven't

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand very well the problem but i think this is the solution.

```
for (int j = 0; j < messageVector.size(); j++){
  for (int i = 0; i < bookVector.size(); i++){
    bool duplicateL = false;

    size_t offset = 0;
    while (((offset = bookVector[i].find(messageVector[j], offset)) != string::npos) && (duplicateL == false)){
      cout << "Found " << messageVector[j] << " at " << i << "," << offset << std::endl;
      ++offset;
      duplicateL = true;
    }
  }
}
```

An extra variable in order to know if is the first time or not.